# Php can't blowfish hash with cost over 17

Tags: php, blowfish

I'm using php's crypt() to hash passwords. I decided to go with blowfish algorithm and use salt. Salts in crypt() determine algorithm so blowfish's salt begins with $2y$xx$ where xx is cost parameter in range 4-31 (Refer to http://php.net/manual/pl/function.crypt.php). I'm also using bin2hex and openssl random generator to get random salt. As I understand it setting it higher will require more computing time and make brute-force attack longer.

My problem is that I can't get my script to work with cost parameter set over 17. When ran from the browser page is loading approx 1min and then stops with blank page. Not even echo. Why is that? How could I use 30 instead of 17? Is this a matter of my php server settings ?

Here's code:

```
<?php
    $reps=17;
    echo 'pre';
    echo crypt('passwdMike',"$2y$".$reps."$".bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22)));    
    echo 'post';
?>
```

Edit: I can go with higher factors from command line. 18 was under minute. 30 waiting over 10minutes now. So it's obviously too much and 12 will suffice.

Comment: Do you have a reason for using 30? Also, please use the PHP [password API](http://php.net/password) rather than doing all this. At 30, PHP is probably timing out.

Comment: This could be a timeout issue, 17 is already a big work factor !

Comment: Does it run on the command line (it does for me, taking about 8 seconds)? 17 is an insanely high work factor with current hardware.

Comment: I don't quite grasp how big 17 factor is. Generating one tooks something like 10 sec. (1 min was for a bunch of hashes). I din't tried it on command line. I'll try php password API.

Comment: Please note that using the password api doesn't mean you can up cost to 30, and also note the default cost is 10, which is considered a good base line. Consider what hardware you have and the time you're willing to wait to hash a password, 12-13 is often a happy medium I seem to see a lot.

Comment: Just read that. Till this point I was using 12 without API, just crypt and aforementioned salt. What API does it just uses crypt and generates salt with one command. I thought using higher factor will slow down time needed to log in and therefore lengthen time of remote attacks.

Comment: They won't mind it :). That's a school project and I got to reduce login time anyway. But thanks for the input.